# What is IsolatedStorageFileStream?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

In examples on how to use `IsolatedStorage` I have found two main techniques:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(appStorage.CreateFile("fileName", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Text");
    writer.Close()
}
```

And the other:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("fileName", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, appStorage)))
{
writeFile.WriteLine("Text");
writeFile.Close();
}
```

My question is: Is there any real difference between these two techniques?

As well as: Is either method usually preffered by developers? Or is it just down to personal Opinion?

Comment: One's a File and the other is a Stream...

Answer (score 4):

`IsolatedStorageFile` is essentially a pointer to the isolated storage file (area) on disk.

`IsolatedStorageFileStream` is an in-memory representation of the data in a file within the isolated storage area.